# TypeScript conditional return type: works for one condition but not for two

Tags: typescript, typechecking, conditional-types

I have a factory function that creates shapes based on a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of shape arguments, for example:

```js
interface CircleArgs { type: "circle", radius: number };
interface SquareArgs { type: "square", length: number };

type ShapeArgs = CircleArgs | SquareArgs;

class Circle { constructor(_: CircleArgs) {}}
class Square { constructor(_: SquareArgs) {}}

type Shape = Circle | Square;

type ShapeOfArgs<Args extends ShapeArgs> = 
   Args extends CircleArgs? Circle :
   Square;

function createShape<Args extends ShapeArgs>(args: Args): ShapeOfArgs<Args> {
    switch (args.type) {
        case "circle": return new Circle(args);
        case "square": return new Square(args);
    }
}
```

Doing it this way not only helps TS to infer the right return type from the argument:

```js
const circle1 = createShape({type: "circle", radius: 1}); // inferred as Circle
const square1 = createShape({type: "square", length: 1}); // inferred as Square
```

But also correctly propagates the return type if I need to wrap the call in another function:

```js
class Container { insert(_: Shape): void {}; }

function createShapeIn<Args extends ShapeArgs>(args: Args, cont: Container) {
    const shape = createShape(args);
    cont.insert(shape);

    return shape;
}

const cont = new Container();
const circle2 = createShapeIn({type: "circle", radius: 1}, cont); // still inferred as Circle
const square2 = createShapeIn({type: "square", length: 1}, cont); // still inferred as Square
```

### However...

If I add just one more type to the mix everything breaks.

Let's add another type of shapes called `Figure`:

```js
interface FigureArgs { type: "figure", amount: number };
class Figure { constructor(_: FigureArgs) {}}
```

Then the our union types will be:

```js
type ShapeArgs = CircleArgs | SquareArgs | FigureArgs;
type Shape = Circle | Square | Figure;
```

Finally, the conditional type is changed to:

```js
type ShapeOfArgs<Args extends ShapeArgs> = 
    Args extends CircleArgs? Circle :
    Args extends SquareArgs? Square :
    Figure;
```

And now this no longer transpiles:

```js
function createShape<Args extends ShapeArgs>(args: Args): ShapeOfArgs<Args> {
    switch (args.type) {
        case "circle": return new Circle(args); // error: Circle not assignable ShapeOfArgs<Args>
        case "square": return new Square(args); // error: Square not assignable ShapeOfArgs<Args>
        case "figure": return new Figure(args); // error: Figure not assignable ShapeOfArgs<Args>
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PS:** I know I can force it using the `as` operator, but that defeats the purpose of type checking.

#### Links to TS playground:

- [Good](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNhAglAcwGdkBvZMATwAcIAuZAIgQ2wkYBpko4ATYAK5EGIAQFsARtGQBfANwBYAFChIsRCgDKARwFwoeQiXJVaDRkV372XHCAJgAFiPFSosxUuWmtjuLXxiZABeNFYcQJIAH2QdPQNIz2VsOCISdEwcMmQEAHsQIjAoAQQwXKgACgB9Bgy2SIBKMhkZZKxUkjjrbLyCopKyyprYqwSjJtIW5W8aX38UULqsmK6DJKUfWL9aAHkYSIAeSOQIAA9IEF5O7cNiAD4Q5GVkF%20Ozi6uwzNuiAH4vtjIOjPF6rCDrGACEClYD5HIGOCQTQ3I5GE7nCCXa7zSJ3Cr6YgMRoMZHzPaHXFkEEvIgAd2AYAQjmQ%20KMADofBNqS8eQhUihmOF2AwDGABFAQMgQBBaQCcKziA1PDyVTl%20UxLPFhdwIGKJVKZSMtQqiErua0lBbkvlCjkhQBGR4IBFIm4VUg%20cwsb6cbh8QTCZD2mRmpS9W2a6yO0LOiCIiCk2juz0a0Y2ZB2BzOIMh9YpNJofJgOCgaTkUBEaBgaokm4NBgAN1ywF4zTksmmSkh0LAsMlsfjiYgAEkQKigu9MZ8h7iTUSjFxemBakWS9KoFylCrw2BkEQbk6XQm3QTTcreUW2RWqxV9-NQ9zReLJXfaJ4rWGbbul2vpKFpbKqCrqWlShjudrfAATIecauvMo7JrMXpCr6PD8EIDDBouwHrmBX57mm0ExkeQ4IR6SGplqvqZk4mEyNh4C-hunhAA)
- [Bad](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNhAglAcwGdkBvZMATwAcIAuZAIgQ2wkYBpko4ATYAK5EGIAQFsARtGQBfANwBYAFChIsRCgDKARwFwoeQiXJVaDRkV372XHCAJgAFiPFSosxSvDR4SZADFgAgEDfGIyChp6JhggkJtkODEAewFwF0lpeWVlUy1HOFowkgBeNFYcYuQAH2QdPVCjGoC4xuJPZWw4IhJ0TBwIhGSQIjAoAQQwZKgACgB9Bj62YoBKMhkZTqxuknrrQeHR8cnp%20YY9tqI10g2tnZbggwORsYmp2YWH%20NX1zaVcqJ1Aq0ZBlJYDWoXFC1QKPCAdJR5IGFCAAeRgxQAPFUIAAPSAgXi7YGGYgAPlByGUyBpyBx%20IghN6FVJRAA-OV%20ig6NTafSCUS6lZLhyocgeUpaV8DAiYGlJsBhsgEAY4JBNCTsU08QLiSjimSZvpiAxVucSeisQayLyaUQAO7AMAIRzII1GAB0eWutqlyu6KGYLMYDAMYBCIGQIAg9s5bHdxBWnj9tIQAaYlga7FDEHDUEj0djUITV2TKf9REDsThIe4uYjUZj0ogJaTvr%20f06hzAypZAEZKSqIGqIBqUTNSHlzCwuZxuHxBMJkH2ZG2lEMXshM9YB2UhyOx7QJ1OM8KEnYHM5l6vPBvRshq-Fd8rVeqSceouZHwY50lUulrzXO4ejQYYwDgUBpHIUBKygMAzmRWgVgYAA3ZJgF4dY5FkHIlDlEAFSVfc3xRABJEAtXCHVGUFQ9WUNY0l2KLgNzARYwIg6MoB9SVU27LcSUHV9R3fRi1ylViPRg6B4KIEkgN4mkwwbOSUU8Tt1341jOOkMpC1A8AdNmNc7x7Gc2AAJiE4cSNociPzMJhzJwOceH4IQGBXFiOMg7jb347cDCsvdhLo%20zJ0-U8sznC8nE8mRvMM3yTP478IGCl8bJEsiQAc6JGDS38UjSNjr0S8Dks8IA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely simple solution would be to make a "dictionary of types", instead of unions and conditional types:

```
// Dictionary of types
type ShapeByType = {
    circle: Circle,
    square: Square,
    figure: Figure
}

function createShape<Args extends ShapeArgs>(args: Args): ShapeByType[Args["type"]] {
    switch (args.type) {
        case "circle": return new Circle(args);
        case "square": return new Square(args);
        case "figure": return new Figure(args);
    }
}

const circle1 = createShape({type: "circle", radius: 1});
//    ^? Circle

// ...

const circle2 = createShapeIn({type: "circle", radius: 1}, container);
//    ^? Circle
```

With this, it is easier to scale to an arbitrary number of Shapes.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#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-0ARlB-IggogwpRM1IeXMRLYnG4fEEwmQXZkTaUAHplwyAHoAfk6hzAyFTBh7ZQQAqFIpHY5TVgMU7sDmc88Xnnbo0ZrQgR77A6HtAvUXM5Y3lwSSpOkj5LncPRoMMYBwKA0jkKApZQGAZzIrQKwMAAbskwC8OsciyDkShciAPJ8ie-ZniiACSIDik0UoynK6GGMQyqqnOxRcO2YCLDBcHhlAHr0omu77iKvaUd+56cUuDK8S6SHQKhRAihBon4kGNZqSiniti+e68YJ0hlLm0HgCZsxLoZnbEgATFJp6DiKdF-mYTATjgU48PwQgMAuPECfBwmeKuG7bm24kHhAjnHs5P4QG5o7-le1K3hA9hOAFMhBZZIU2eJgGxU5VEubRIDudEjDFVOIFpHxj55bBBWeEAA)

Comment: First I thought it magically worked, but then if you look carefully, the return types of both `createShare` and `createShapeIn` are suddenly `Circle | Square | Figure` in all three cases which is definitely _not_ what I need.

Comment: Indeed the initially proposed solution was overly complex, and TS could not correlate the `args` with the return type. Here is a much simpler solution, which works.